# test upload image with laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, upload

I am testing a controller that upload and resize an image with Laravel and [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize) plugin.

Here is the controller:

```
$file = request()
    ->file('file')
    ->store('images/avatar', 'public');

Image::make(storage_path('app/public/' . $file))
    ->resize(200, 200, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    })
    ->save();
```

Upload is working great, but in tests, file is uploaded to `storage/framework/testing/disks/public/images/avatar/` while in dev, it is send to `storage/app/public/images/avatar/`

Result is that tests are failing on `Image::make(storage_path('app/public/' . $file))` when running.

Anyone know how could I fix it???

Comment: You try to access an image in this path `storage_path('app/public/' . $file)` . make sure it exists.

Comment: In, dev, it works and this file exists, but the `store()` method select a different folder when doing in web and testing.

Comment: you can try to include the absolute path and not the storage_path()

Comment: maybe changing .env attributes such as 'APP_ENV' and 'APP_DEBUG' to 'product' and 'false' works.